# Is there a way to programmatically instantiate an existing widget to a thingsboard existing dashboard?

Tags: thingsboard

I'm trying to automatise the adding of devices to thingsboard.

I already made an api endpoint that creates a new device and answers with it's newly created ID. Now I want for this device to be visible on a dashboard with the led widget.

I want to do this prgrammatically , if possible alongside the api call for the creation of said device.

Right now I'm investigating dashboard import export , is it possible to import/export it programmatically ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel Thank you , I indeed read them, unfortunately I think this question doesn't really relate to an actual example, but if you see a way to implement said example that would be great ! Again thank you for your comment ^^